# Stopping & starting animation after pressing on button (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, animation, button

Hello :) I've created and animated my own progress bar to the simple music player that I'm making. Now I want to know is it possible to start and pause this animation with the same buttons that are used to play and pause audio file. 
Code sample:

```
<div id="progressBar">
    <div id="track"></div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <button><<<</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('music').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('music').pause()">Pause</button>
    <button>>>></button><br>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('music').volume += 0.1">Vol+</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('music').volume -= 0.1">Vol-</button>
</div>
```

Animation:

```
var val = 0, progressBar, track;

function progressFunc(){

  if(val>100){
    val=0;
  }

  progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  track = document.getElementById('track');

  track.style.width = val + "%";
  val +=8;

  setTimeout(progressFunc, 1000);
}

 window.addEventListener("load", progressFunc, false);
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! All we need is a couple of small tweaks:

- First, we move the timer (the `setInterval` call) out of the animation function. This way, we have better control of what gets animated and how
- Then, we add a function that stops the timer and (optionally) resets the bar to its original state
- Finally, we add two very simple click handlers and attach them to the buttons

Putting it all together:

```
let currentValue = 0
let timer = 0

// clickEvent is of type MouseEvent
function playMusic(clickEvent) {
  if (timer) return  // animation is already active

  clickEvent.preventDefault()  // cancel the click event so it does not cause unwanted side effects
  document.getElementById('music').play()
  timer = setInterval(animateBar, 1000)
}

function stopMusic(clickEvent) {
  if (!timer) return  // we already stopped animation

  clickEvent.preventDefault()
  clearInterval(timer)
  timer = 0

  document.getElementById('music').pause()
}

function animateBar() {
  const track = document.getElementById('track')

  if (currentValue > 100) currentValue = 0
  track.style.width = `${currentValue}%`
  currentValue +=8
}

// Attach the event handlers
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('playButton').addEventListener('click', playMusic) 
  document.getElementById('pauseButton').addEventListener('click', stopMusic) 
}, false);
```

Now we just need to tweak the markup little bit

```
...
    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
    <button id="pauseButton">Pause</button>
...
```

As a side note: a simple animation like this could be also done with CSS, which greatly reduces and simplifies the JavaScript code necessary to animate/stop animation

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works, thank you :) Next question is can I hook up that progress bar to the actual song duration?

Comment: Of course, the most straightforward way would be to use "closures" to pass the song duration and current playhead position into the "animateBar" method, which will calculate percentage accordingly. So instead of "timer = setInterval(animateBar, 1000)" you would use something like "timer = setInterval(() => { animateBar(playheadPos, duratioin) }, 1000)" where playheadPos and duration are be local vars that you populate from the track metadata